# Uninstalling VirtualBox

Tags: apt, software-installation, virtualbox, uninstall

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit. I was trying to uninstall VirtualBox, but I got a lot of errors which ended with a warning telling me that my Software Centre has failed. I restarted the system and was going to try again. I ran: `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` before trying anything else.

When I ran the upgrade command, the VirtualBox automatically got installed along with it, but after throwing a lot of warnings at me (I don't remember exactly what those were).

I think I should uninstall this and start fresh but when I try to uninstall using `apt-get remove virtualbox* --purge`, I got these results:

```
ananthan@ananthan-X556UQK~$ sudo apt-get remove virtualbox* --purge 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-source' for glob 'virtualbox*' 
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-utils' for glob 'virtualbox*' 
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-ose' for glob 'virtualbox*' 
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-modules' for glob 'virtualbox*' 
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-additions-iso' for glob 'virtualbox*' 
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-dkms' for glob 'virtualbox*' 
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-dkms' for glob 'virtualbox*'
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-ext-pack' for glob 'virtualbox*' 
Note, selecting 'virtualbox' for glob 'virtualbox*' 
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-source' for glob 'virtualbox*' 
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-ose-fuse' for glob 'virtualbox*' 
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-qt' for glob 'virtualbox*' 
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-2.0' for glob 'virtualbox*' 
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-2.1' for glob 'virtualbox*' 
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-2.2' for glob 'virtualbox*' 
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-modules' for glob 'virtualbox*' 
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-3.0' for glob 'virtualbox*' 
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-3.1' for glob 'virtualbox*' 
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-3.2' for glob 'virtualbox*' 
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-4.0' for glob 'virtualbox*' 
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-4.1' for glob 'virtualbox*' 
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-4.2' for glob 'virtualbox*' 
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-4.3' for glob 'virtualbox*' 
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-5.0' for glob 'virtualbox*' 
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-5.1' for glob 'virtualbox*' 
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-dbg' for glob 'virtualbox*' 
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-X11' for glob 'virtualbox*' 
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-guest-additions' for glob 'virtualbox*' 
Package 'virtualbox-ose' is not installed, so not removed 
Package 'virtualbox-ose-fuse' is not installed, so not removed 
Note, selecting 'virtualbox-dkms' instead of 'virtualbox-modules' 
Package 'virtualbox-2.0' is not installed, so not removed 
Package 'virtualbox-2.1' is not installed, so not removed 
Package 'virtualbox-2.2' is not installed, so not removed 
Package 'virtualbox-3.0' is not installed, so not removed 
Package 'virtualbox-3.1' is not installed, so not removed 
Package 'virtualbox-3.2' is not installed, so not removed 
Package 'virtualbox-4.0' is not installed, so not removed 
Package 'virtualbox-4.1' is not installed, so not removed 
Package 'virtualbox-4.2' is not installed, so not removed 
Package 'virtualbox-4.3' is not installed, so not removed 
Package 'virtualbox-5.0' is not installed, so not removed 
Package 'virtualbox-guest-additions' is not installed, so not removed 
Package 'virtualbox-5.1' is not installed, so not removed. Did you mean 'virtualbox-5.1:i386'?   
Package 'virtualbox' is not installed, so not removed 
Package 'virtualbox-dbg' is not installed, so not removed 
Package 'virtualbox-dkms' is not installed, so not removed 
Package 'virtualbox-ext-pack' is not installed, so not removed
```

It is telling me that it is unable to install anything because nothing has been installed, however I am able to open VirtualBox so it must be installed. I am apprehensive about trying it out in this form.

How do I uninstall this? Or should I try to use this as it is?

Comment: Maybe you are using Oracle VirtualBox instead of the VirtualBox from the official Ubuntu 16.04 repositories. When you open VirtualBox and select *Help* -> *About VirtualBox* does it say "Oracle"?

Comment: How did you install VIrtualbox in the first, this will determine how its removed.

Comment: @karel. Thanks a lot. I had installed the oracle VirtualBox and that was the problem. I believe I managed to uninstall it now.

Comment: This tells you which version you have `sudo dpkg -l | grep virtualbox` - then, if installed, remove it with e.g. `sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-5.1:i386`.

Comment: Oh and for 16.04 I'd really prefer the more recent Oracle version over the repository one.

Comment: @Takkat a better command might be `dpkg -l *virtualbox* | grep ii`, as this would catch more, ie: `virtualbox-5.1.22`, etc. and only show installed packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are using Oracle VirtualBox instead of the VirtualBox from the official Ubuntu 16.04 repositories. When you open VirtualBox and select *Help* -> *About VirtualBox* does it say "Oracle"? If so, the terminal output in your question indicates that VirtualBox from the default Ubuntu repositories is not currently installed.

> I had installed Oracle VirtualBox and that was the problem.